# how to add a Border on a container Div

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, border

I'm trying to border a div that contains 4 fa-icons. Since I've set the parent div as `Container`, the border is automatically occupying large padding on the left & right sides horizontally. I've also tried nesting bootstrap grids, but it's not helping. Can anyone please help with this?

NOTE: Padding should not be greater than 1px on all sides and the div should exactly be in the center of the page.

[image]
**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="socialIcons">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x "></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
                  <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i>
              </a>
            </div> 
        </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#socialIcons {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px !important;
    border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** After applying Jeff's answer, this is closer to what I needed, but still has the automatic padding on the right side of the GitHub icon. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Since you added the padding to the `.container`, it will border the ENTIRE width and height of the `container`. Are you just wanting the border to be 1px wider and taller than all 4 icons?

Comment: Yes, border should barely cover the 4 fa-icons.

Comment: the container css class is a reserved one if u use bootstrap with a fixed width adjusting to the current breakpoint. If u need a full-width container, I would suggest to use .container-fluid then use display flex, center align a div in that container and just add display flex there too. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/

Comment: check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mqfcz

Comment: I checked the stackblitz, it's close but still has the same issue which I updated in the answer. Your answer is also leaving an automatic padding on the right of GitHub icon. Now, could this be a fa-icon issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (when you swap your icons with my `span`'s, it should give you the proper padding on top and bottom):

[Codpen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/RwWLNdj)

Instead of hard coding `text-align: center;`, just add the class `text-center` through Bootstrap. Also, notice I added `justify-content-center` to the row.

```
    <div class="container text-center" id="socialIcons">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div class="border">
         <a href="https://www.google.com">
           <span>google</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <span>youtube</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <span>fb</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <span>twitter</span>
        </a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
    #socialIcons {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 300px !important;
    }

    .border {
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 1px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff! This is closer but still has an issue. I have updated the question with it.

Comment: I have edited the Codepen with icons from FontAwesome and it displays how you want. You must have something underlying in your code to push it right

Comment: I'll check if something is interfering! Thanks a lot Jeff! Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" id="socialIcons">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid white;">
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x "></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
              <i class="fab fa-github fa-3x"></i>
          </a>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

I hope above code will helps you

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but still, this leaves padding of around 50px automatically on the right and left sides.

Answer (score -1):

If your icons should be center-aligned - you don't need to use div element with `container` class. Just add a div wrapper with custom class, and add your styles on it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I need container class for my other code which will be written inside that same div later.